# why ssl of Entrust ssl certificate is required for APNS

Tags: iphone, ssl, apple-push-notifications

Hi all
why apple has given link of entrust ssl ,is it necessary ?
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html
see at first note:

Note: To establish a TLS session with APNs, an Entrust Secure CA root certificate must be installed on the provider’s server. If the server is running Mac OS X, this root certificate is already in the keychain. On other systems, the certificate might not be available. You can download this certificate from the Entrust SSL Certificates website.

Comment: You have a perfectly good explanation in the note.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the certificate is necessary to establish a TLS session with APNs.
But you don't need to buy a certificate from Entrust. (I guess this was what you thought, because there are huge $xxx for a certificate boxes on the Entrust website)

The APNs uses a secure connection to a server that uses a certificate from Entrust. And this connection would fail when the CA root certificate wouldn't be installed on your computer. All "regular" certificates are only valid if the root certificate is known to your computer. And this is the file that they want you to download.

But most likely the Entrust Secure CA root cert is already installed. I used APNs from Ubuntu, and Arch Linux, and I installed nothing from Entrust. This is from my arch install, all necessary root ca certificates are already there:

```
[root@dellbook certs]# ls /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust*
/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Global_Secure_Personal_CA.pem
/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Global_Secure_Server_CA.pem
/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Secure_Personal_CA.pem
/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem
/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
```

Comment: please help me.Now I am using urbanAir for APNS .b/c i used my server for APNS but there was connection says "Connection refused" by apple.so how i can solve it

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't have to buy one of the Entrust certificates; you just have to download the certificate authority certificate (which is free) from their website. Apple should have made this more clear. I found the current link to this, which may not work forever, but for now here it is: https://www.entrustdatacard.com/pages/root-certificates-download